# What is a symplectic structure on a smooth vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles, projection, fiber-bundles

We just had the definition of a symplectic structure on a vector bundle in the lecture and I am having trouble understanding it
Definition: Let $\pi : E \to M$  be a smooth vector bundle. Then a symplectic structure on E is a smooth section $\omega \in \Gamma( \bigwedge^2 E^*)$ such that $\forall x \in M$ the value $\omega(x) = \omega_x$ is a symplectic form on $E_x = \pi^{-1}(x)$.

I know in general what vector bundles and smooth sections are. But I don't quite understand the bundle structure on $\bigwedge^2 E^*$ or the projection map there.
And consequently I don't understand why as a smooth section $\omega$ is a collection of symplectic forms on the fibers.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: In general, $\bigwedge^k(E)$ as a set is the union $\bigcup\limits_{x\in M}\bigwedge^k(E_x)$, and the map $\pi_k$ takes an element of $\bigwedge^k(E_x)$ (the $k^{th}$ exterior power of the vector space $E_x$) and maps it to $x$. There is pretty much only one reasonable way in which to define the bundle charts; this makes $\bigwedge^k(E)$ into a vector bundle over $M$. A symplectic form on $(E,\pi,M)$ is a section of the bundle $\bigwedge^2(E^*)$ (where $E^*$ is the dual bundle) such that for each $x\in M$, $\omega(x)\in E_x^*\wedge E_x^*$ has the property that it's a symplectic form on $E_x$.

Comment: So, being symplectic is an extra condition on a section of $\bigwedge^2(E^*)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) . I get now why the definition makes sense in general. But could you maybe explain what local trivializations of $\bigwedge^2 V$ look like ? Or give a reference so that I could read up on dual bundles.

Comment: Dieudonne's treatise on analysis Vol 3, Chpater 16 (i.e the first half of the book) is all about smooth manifolds theory, and it talks about vector bundles (direct/Whitney sums, tensor products, exterior powers, Hom vector bundles) (I'm sure other references exist; but I just don't know of many). But really the definitions are "natural". For example, have you seen the definition of the cotangent bundle $T^*M$? What about the tensor bundles $T^r_s(M)$? The way you get charts on these spaces almost verbatim transfers over to general vector bundles.

Comment: or you could just search for a bit on google to see how many of the basic linear-algebraic constructions extend in a natural manner to the vector bundle setting (there are many small sets of lecture notes which describe this sort of stuff).

Comment: Thank you peek-a-boo. I have been able to construct explicit local trivialisations of $\bigwedge^2 E^*$ and the endomorphism bundle. (Hope they are correct :D). I have no idea what tensor bundles are, but thankfully I didn't encounter them (yet)

Comment: They're the obvious thing one expects them to be. If $(E,\pi_E,M)$ and $(F,\pi_E,M)$ are vector bundles then we can define as a set, $E\otimes F=\bigcup_{x\in M}(E_x\otimes F_x)$, and the projection takes elements of $E_x\otimes F_x$ to $x$. Defining the bundle charts is again a simple exercise in coming up with "reasonable and obvious" definitions. So, $E\otimes F$ is the bundle whose fibers are the tensor product of the fibers of $E$ and $F$. You mentioned the endomorphism bundle... we can also define the Hom bundle $\text{Hom}(E,F)$ (it's fibers are linear maps $E_x\to F_x$) and so on.